# How can I make jquery autocomplete search in all the words seperated by a whitespace

Tags: jquery-autocomplete

Suppose in the source of jQuery autocomplete I have a word like SELINA RISEWA MIL.

But if I type SELINA MIL jQuery autocomplete doesn't return that option. How can I change that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement this in your search logic from where you are returning your JSON response containing the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expressions-- say like this

```
        $('#elem').autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term, ""));
                var data = $.grep( array, function(value) {
                    return matcher.test( value.label || value.value || value );
                });
                response(data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: sorry Vitthal Mbut again it cannot find SELINA RISEWA  MIL; it only finds selena MILOWSA TIGROWA, SELENA MILEWSKA MILEWSKA and so on but again it doesn't serch in the last name