# Make jQuery AutoComplete Work with Multiple Words ("Jumping Over" a Word)

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm using [jQuery's "AutoComplete"](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete) and everything is great except one thing.  It can't seem to find suggestions if the user skips over a word.

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshmanakumar/fjHKN/1/) is a working version of what I'm talking about.  If you search for **win someone** it will properly display the suggestion of "win the heart of someone".  However, I don't understand how to implement this in "jquery.autocomplete.js".

I've tried looking at settings in

```
lookupFilter: function (suggestion, originalQuery, queryLowerCase) {
    return suggestion.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) !== -1;
},
```

but it's not working.

[This person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428071/how-can-i-make-jquery-autocomplete-search-in-all-the-words-seperated-by-a-whites) seems to have the same question and it's unanswered at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/z0oxa63r/2/

```
 $.ui.autocomplete.filter = function (array, term) {
        var regTab = term.split(" ");
        var regex = regTab.join('[\\w ]*');
        var matcher = new RegExp("^" + regex, "i");
        return $.grep(array, function (value) {
            return matcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
        });
    };
```

Comment: Where might I incorporate this in https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete/blob/master/src/jquery.autocomplete.js though?

Comment: Do you mean by a pull request?

Comment: No, I mean I've downloaded this package and am using it and I'd like to edit the code to implement your function.  The relevant file is here (https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete/blob/master/src/jquery.autocomplete.js), but I don't see where in that file I would insert your function.

Comment: Can't you do it like I did in the fiddle ?

Comment: I want to, but I don't know where to place your function in the code in this file (https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete/blob/master/src/jquery.autocomplete.js).

Comment: Do you have a html file with input file inside?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109324/discussion-between-gtilflm-and-tim-b).